# jsp return the radio box value and auto select

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a order.jsp which has a form containing a list of radio boxes and textfields. When submit button is clicked, it will forward to validate.jsp to validate the input data. If they are not valid, it will return to order.jsp again.
I want to keep the user's input data in the form. I use request.getSession().getAttribute and request.getSession().setAttribute to return the input data and successfully works in text.

```
String date = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("date");
<input id="date" name="date" type="text" size="25" value="<%=date%>">
```

However, I have no idea in radio box. Even i can get the selected value, how it can be used to select that particular button back which is clicked by the user before?

```
<INPUT TYPE=radio name="weight" value="1" id="weight1">1 pound 
<INPUT TYPE=radio name="weight" value="1.5" id="weight2">1.5 pound
<INPUT TYPE=radio name="weight" value="2" id="weight3">2 pounds
```